# Differentiability of two way defined function.

Tags: calculus

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be two differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Now how to check the differentiability of the following function at $x=a$

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} p(x), & \mbox{if } x\mbox{ $\geq a$} \\ q(x), & \mbox{if } x\mbox{ $ <a$} \end{cases} $$?. 
I usually check it as , if   $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} p^{'}(x)$=$\lim_{x\to a^{-}} q^{'}(x)$ then $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Am i right in this calculation.? Please suggest me  is it  right method to check differentiability of the function $f$  at $x=a.$?

Comment: Please some one suggest me...

Comment: No.  You must check that $\lim_{x \to a^+}  \frac{p(x)-p(a)}{x-a}  = \lim_{x -\to a^-}  \frac{q(x)-p(a)}{x-a}.$

Comment: You need to check differentiability of $f$ not continuity of $p',q'$.

Comment: @mattbiesecker if q(x) is also defined at x=a then the method of parvesh kumar will work??

Comment: @Yogesh.  If $q(a)$ is defined, then it must equal $p(a),$ otherwise $f$ will not even be a function.

Comment: yes if it is defined  and equal to p(a) then the method of parvesh kumar will work??

Comment: @mattbiesecker now right sir?

Comment: @YOGESH.  See below.

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum you need continuity. What condition is necessary at $x=a$
for continuity?

You need $\lim_{x \downarrow a} {f(x)-f(a) \over x-a} = \lim_{x \uparrow a} {f(x)-f(a) \over x-a}$.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically answer why the OP's method is insufficient, consider the following scenarios.

1) A case where the derivative exists, but the left/hand hand limits  do not exist is $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}  x^2 \sin(1/x) \ \ &  x\neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{array} \right.\ \ .$$     Then both  of $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f'(x)$ do not exist.  However, $f'(0)=0$ via the definition of differentiability.

2) A case where the left and right hand limits of $f'$ agree, but $f'(0)$ does not exist is rather trivial:
$$
f'(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}  1 \ \ &  x\geq 0 \\ 0 & x<0 \end{array} \right.\ \ . 
$$
Then $\lim_{x\to 0^+}  f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-} f'(x)=0,$ but $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: nicely explaned...thanks a lot...